# How to alert each function name from loaded js file?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, firebug, mozilla

I wonder, is there some way to `console.log` or alert running function name. I mean can I override all the function execution, and append something like `console.log(this.arguments.callee.name` from Mozilla's firebug console?

Answer (score 0):

There is also [JavaScript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/) that will log all function calls ("executed scripts"). Logging function names only will be hard however - most functions don't have names (anonymous functions assigned to object / object prototype properties).